# É melhor parametrizar seu PreparedStatement mesmo que o valor seja fixo?

Tags: java, sql, sql-injection

Leio sempre o blog [Java Revisited](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.br) e estive lendo hoje o artigo [Why use PreparedStatement in Java JDBC – Example Tutorial](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.br/2012/03/why-use-preparedstatement-in-java-jdbc.html). Em determinado momento o autor fala sobre parametrização de queries, que é melhor, mais seguro e mais performático usar a parametrização oferecida pela API do que concatenar Strings e utiliza os exemplos abaixo:

SQL Query 1: PreparedStatement utilizando concatenação de String

```
String loanType = getLoanType();
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select banks from loan where loan_type = " + loanType);
```

SQL Query 2: Query parametrizada utilizando PreparedStatement

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select banks from loan where loan_type = ?");
prestmt.setString(1, loanType);
```

Ele explica que ao utilizar a parametrização o driver JDBC irá verificar os dados e com String concatenada não, ele irá apenas executar o SQL enviado, ou seja, se tivermos aquele famoso `OR 1 = 1` a query sempre retornará verdadeiro e tá aí o famoso SQL Injection.

O que não ficou muito claro pra mim é porque um é mais performático que o outro e mais, isso valeria pro caso de eu ter um parâmetro sempre estático também, por exemplo:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(select * from usuarios where ativo = 'S');
```

Ou é mais performático usar como abaixo:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(select * from usuarios where ativo = ?);
pstmt.setString(1, "S");
```

Outra dúvida, nesse caso acho que a questão de segurança é a mesma, pois como não há passagem de parâmetro através do usuário não há como haver o ataque, certo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## TL;DR

Na maioria dos casos usar *Prepared Statements* é melhor, mais seguro e mais performático. Mas não é uma regra.

## Como funcionam os *Prepared Statements*

Quando você cria um *prepared statement*, o driver JDBC envia a query **sem os parâmetros** para ser compilada pelo servidor de banco de dados.

Ao executar o *statement* com os parâmetros definidos, o driver irá enviar **somente os valores** e solicitar a execução da *query* a partir do *cache*.

A vantagem em relação ao desempenho (*performance*) ocorre a partir da segunda execução, pois o servidor de banco de dados já está com a query compilada em *cache*. Ele não precisa interpretá-la novamente. Em geral, queries que executam apenas uma vez podem usar apenas o *Statement*.

A vantagem em relação à segurança consiste em que o servidor de banco de dados recebe a *query* e os parâmetros em momentos diferentes, então não há risco de misturar um parâmetro do usuário com uma cláusula SQL, resultando num *SQL Injection*.

## O que são *Parâmetros*?

Quanto à questão do que é ou não um parâmetro, se o concatena ou não na *query*, considere a origem e a possibilidade de mudança do seu valor.

Por exemplo, em um método `getClientesAtivos()` com uma cláusula `WHERE status='ATIVO'` não faz sentido colocar o valor `'ATIVO'` num parâmetro, já que ele não muda.

Por outro lado, se o método fosse `getClientes(String status)`, então você *deve* definir esse valor como parâmetro.

Mesmo que o valor não venha do usuário, se ele **variar**, coloque-o como parâmetro, pois o driver JDBC somente enviará a *query* uma vez ao servidor de banco de dados, isso írá melhorar o desempenho.

## Você já falou de desempenho e segurança, mas porque *Prepared Statements* são melhores?

São melhores porque são mais seguros e performáticos, ora!

Comment: TL;DR pra questão ou pro blog?

Comment: Pra resposta dele :)

Comment: Eu vi isso em alguns sites do StackExchange em inglês e adotei. A princípio eu achei estranho, mas depois percebi que [TL;DR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn't_read) também pode ser usado para resumir seu próprio conteúdo.

Answer (score 6):

Que usar Prepared Statements é mais seguro do que concatenar os parâmetros diretamente na query, isso é verdade. Entretanto, se o parâmetro é fixo, não vejo porque passá-lo como um parâmetro do Prepared Statement. Por mim pode entrar direto na query.

A não ser que futuramente você pretenda deixar esse parâmetro configurável, aí acho que já vale a pena deixá-lo no método `setString`.

Comment: Quanto à segurança também não há impacto, correto?

Comment: Entre usar um valor fixo ou uma variável, correto, desde que você use o método `setString` :)

Comment: E se eu fizer `PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(select * from usuarios where ativo = 'S')`, como não há parametrização via usuário não há questão de segurança e não usei `setString`.

Comment: Isso é verdade, só citei que seria uma boa deixar o `setString` mesmo com o valor fixo caso futuramente você queira aceitar um parâmetro no lugar. Aí é com você!

Comment: Ah sim, entendi agora. Obrigado.

Comment: e os Prepared Statements são pré-compilados na base de dados (quase uma stored procedure criada em runtime), ai a vantagem de velocidade também (além do sand-boxing dos parâmetros)

Comment: É, a questão de ser pré-compilado ficou clara na resposta aceita, @SparK.