# Retornar string em uma consulta no SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragment

Preciso retornar o nome de um usuário em uma consulta SQLITE:
Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
public String verificarUsuario(String login)
    {

        try
        {

        String selectQuery = "select nome from usuarios where login = " + login;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String nomeString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tipoFunc"));

        StringBuilder conversor = new StringBuilder();
        conversor.append(nomeString);
        return conversor.toString();


        }
```

Mas está aparecendo o seguinte erro:

> no such column: lgomes (code 1): , while compiling: select nome from usuarios where login=lgomes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O nome do usuário precisa estar entre aspas para representar uma `string`.

Se não usar as aspas o banco de dados vai tentar comparar a coluna `login` com outra coluna. Veja a mensagem de erro:

> no such column: **lgomes**

Em tradução livre

> Nenhuma coluna chamada **lgomes**

Seu código deveria ser algo como:

```
String selectQuery = "select nome from usuarios where login = '" + login + "'";
```

O segundo erro é porque você tem que usar o *index* da coluna:

```
String nomeString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nome"))
```

---

Seria bom notar que montar *queries* concatenando *strings* podem deixar seu aplicativo suscetível a ataques de injeção SQL. Tome cuidado com isto.

Leia estas perguntas se quiser se informar melhor.

- [Por que consultas SQL parametrizadas(nome = ?) previnem SQL Injection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63447/18246)
- [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/18246) (É em PHP, mas a ideia geral é a mesma).
- [O que é o ponto de interrogação em uma query?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22621/18246)
- [É melhor parametrizar seu PreparedStatement mesmo que o valor seja fixo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5901/18246)
- [Como acontece um SQL Injection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100729/18246)

Comment: Obrigado!! Deu certo, agora deu `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.`

Comment: @LucasCharles esse erro é porque você tem que colocar o index correto: `String nomeString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nome"))`

Comment: Bem, aí já é outro problema, @LucasCharles Acho que você deve abrir uma nova pergunta, com esta informação e o _stacktrace_ do erro.

Comment: @LucasCharles cursor.getColumnIndex("nome")

Comment: @acklay MUITO obrigado